# Highcharts: How to link legend to categories rather than to bar series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using Highcharts to display a bar chart, is there a built-in way to link legend items to categories rather than to series?  As such I would see a chart with a bunch of bars, and when I click a legend item it would show or hide just the bar(s) associated with a single category.

Thanks

Comment: You can use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/whFvA/4/

Comment: I like where this is going, but would prefer that the legend itself control the visibility of the bars, rather than a separate set of controls.

Comment: You can prepare a HTML legend or catch a [legendItemClick event](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.legendItemClick) and then call actions which are in my fiddle. This is only simple demo, so you can develop on your own.

Comment: Sebastian, simply using legendItemClick is not sufficient, as I need the legend to display one item per bar.  You suggested "prepare a HTML legend".  That sounds to me like reimplementing the entire legend.  Can you please clarify?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a built in way.

You can fake it in a number of ways, however.

One way is to use a separate series for each category, set `grouping` to false, dummy the x values to hover around the actual category value.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    grouping: false,
    pointRange: 0.2
  }
},    
series: [{
  name: 'Group A',
  data: [[-0.25,5],[0,7],[0.25,6]]
}]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/x1cdz54r/

Comment: I have tried something like this pattern, and it works.  But it means that everything else I try to do thereafter with the bar (column) chart must also work within that pattern, which causes other problems.  Hence I am trying to use the normal pattern and find a way to change the legend behavior, hoping that will be the lesser of two difficulties.

Comment: Yes. This is very far out of the ordinary behavior of a chart, so it's bound to be bumpy :)  Perhaps if you clarify the purpose of doing this, alternate solutions may be presented.

Comment: The idea is for the user to be able to interactively select just the categories that he/she is interested in seeing.

Comment: I have modified your fiddle a little to work more closely with the behavior I want.  See http://jsfiddle.net/dkent600/e6357a22/1/.  However, both your and my versions behave strangely when clicking on the legend items, particularly when clicking on the middle item, where the bar disappears, but the other two bars don't redraw to fill the empty space.  Any idea how to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: That is the expected behavior with this set up.  Clicking the first or the last set change the extremes of the data displayed, and therefore causes the axis to reset.  Clicking the middle does not change the min or the max, so the axis is not affected.  If you want to completely remove both the data, and the category entry itself, you need to reset the categories on each click, and redraw the chart.  I believe Sebastian's example may be more what you need.

Comment: Sebastian's example doesn't work with the built-in legend, as far as I can see.  When using the built-in legend, I assume that if you remove a category from the chart then you're going to lose the corresponding item in the legend, and thus lose any ability to reshow the category.

Comment: Back to the example where I noted that when clicking on the legend items, particularly when clicking on the middle item, the bar disappears, but the other two bars don't redraw to fill the empty space.

Your response, jlbriggs, was that the set of categories displayed in the yAxis is not affected unless the axis extents change.  Regardless of the reason for the behavior, it is clear that there *is* a way to display a subset of categories in the yAxis while still displaying all of the categories in the legend.  

This is what I need, but it is not clear to me how to do it.

Comment: Look at sebastian's follow-up comment - the legendItemClick is what you need, combined with the rest of his set up. Trying to remove the middle of an axis is not at all related to setting the extremes of the axis, which is what happens when you hide your first/last data points. Chasing that route will not help you.

Comment: Sebastian's suggestion has only a single series and the legend contains only one item.  I need the legend to contain one item per bar, and it seems that, short of reimplementing the entire legend, the only way to achieve this is to implement each bar as its own series, as you, jlbriggs, have described.

That means that I need to be able to hide/show a series and its related category in the xAxis without affecting the visibility of the legend item associated with the series.

Thanks for any suggestions or corrections.

Comment: Recreate your example as live demo, including legend with single item.

Comment: Doug - yes, it seems you need a combination of our approaches if you want all of those things.  However - it would probably be easier just to reproduce an external legend to replace the default, and rebuild your data and categories, and redraw the chart, with each click.

Comment: Sebastian, I'm sorry I don't understand your last comment,  Can you please clarify?

"Recreate your example as live demo, including legend with single item"

Comment: I mean recreate your example as live demo on jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I did that, referenced above, and here again:  http://jsfiddle.net/dkent600/e6357a22/1/

In any case, I am about to enter the answer I came up with, below

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I found no out-of-the-box way to do this.  But I found a solution that works, as follows:

1. correlate each bar with a single series (see fiddle referenced above)
2. in legendItemClick:

   - manually show or hide the series associated with the clicked-on legend item
   - given visibility of each category, recompute the indices of each visible category and update each visible bar series data[0].x with the new index of the category with which it is associated (use point.update())
   - call xAxis.setCategories with a list of the categories you want to be currently visible
   - call xAxis.setExtremes with the new extremes for the category indices

Here is a very simple example of the above:

```
legendItemClick = function (e) {
        var seriesClicked = e.currentTarget;
        var chart = seriesClicked.chart;
        var axis = chart.xAxis[0]

    if (seriesClicked.visible) {
        seriesClicked.hide();
        chart.series[2].data[0].update( { x: 1 });
        axis.setCategories(['Group A', 'Group C'], false)
        axis.setExtremes(0, 1, true)

    } else {
        seriesClicked.show();
        chart.series[2].data[0].update( { x: 2 });
        axis.setCategories(['Group A', 'Group B', 'Group C'], false)
        axis.setExtremes(0, 2, true)
    }
    return false;
}
```

And a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dkent600/e6357a22/17/